# Python Sqlalchemy - How to compare tables/rows and identify deltas?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compare the data in 2 tables so that I can identify what has changed and apply necessary `update`s or `insert`s.

The most obvious way (to me) of doing this in a database is to outer join the two tables and identify new or modified values this way, but I am  wondering if there is a built-in SQLAlchemy capability that, for example, given 2 tables it can identify deltas?

This difference identification capability is implemented beautifully in python with `set` notation.

#### Example "tables" (sets) with multiple rows (tuples)

```
table1 = {('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')
table2 = {('a', 'DELTA'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')}
diff = table2.difference(table1)
# {('a', 'DELTA'), ('e', 'f')}
```

#### Expected outcome:

1. Row `('a', 'b')` in `table1` should be `UPDATE`ed to `('a', 'DELTA')`
2. Row `('e', 'f')` should be `INSERT`ed to `table1`

I saw the concept of a [compare](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=compare#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.compare) referenced in the `core` docs but I could not find any examples or any details in addition to the basic definition.

How do others handle situations such as this using SQLAlchemy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy supports on_conflict_do_update(), something like the below may sort you:

```
with testing.db.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(
            insert(users).on_conflict_do_update(),
            dict(id=1, name="name1"),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks.  But this appears to be specific to postgres, i am using mysql.